# Bash: Easy way to know whether there is a thread with specified thread id?

Tags: linux, bash, process, scripting, ps

I need to know if there is a thread with specified thread id. Probably I can look at all process's threads and see if it exists, or get all thread list with ps command and try to find thread in output, but isn't there a simpler way?

Comment: You might want to have a look [here](http://superuser.com/questions/632979/if-i-know-the-pid-number-of-a-process-how-can-i-get-its-name)

Comment: I mean thread, not a process

Comment: Parse the output of `ps -eLf`. Source: https://superuser.com/questions/80556/how-do-you-view-all-threads-running-on-linux

Comment: Or you can go through the list of threads from a particular process using `pgrep -w`

Comment: Yes that was my second difficult way, maybe `ps -e -T` is better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are on Linux?

If you know the process id you can use the proc filesystem to figure out whether a certain thread exists or not.

Example:

Process ID $PID 14456

Thread ID $TID 14465

If the directory `/proc/$PID/task/$TID` exists, the thread is running.

If you don't know the process ID you can let the shell do the globbing for you:

```
if [ -d /proc/*/task/$TID ]; then echo found; fi
```

Comment: Great!
I knew about `/proc`, but not about `/proc/<pid>/task`, thank you.